# How to use scipy `minimize` on a difference between two vectors?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have two vectors `w1` and `w2` (each of length 100), and I want to minimize the sum of their absolute difference i.e.

```
import numpy as np


def diff(w: np.ndarray) -> float:
    """Get the sum of absolute differences in the vector w.

    Args:
        w: A flattened vector of length 200, with the first 100 elements
            pertaining to w1, and the last 100 elements pertaining to w2.

    Returns:
        sum of absolute differences.
    """
    return np.sum(np.absolute(w[:100] - w[-100:]))
```

I need to write `diff()` as only taking one argument since `scipy.opyimize.minimize` requires the array passed to the `x0` argument to be 1 dimensional.

As for constraints, I have

1. `w1` is fixed and **not** allowed to change
2. `w2` is allowed to change
3. The sum of absolute values `w2` is between 0.1 and 1.1: `0.1 <= sum(abs(w2)) <= 1.1`
4. `|w2_i| < 0.01` for any element `i` in `w2`

I am confused as to how we code these constraints using the [`Bounds`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.Bounds.html) and [`LinearConstraints`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint.html#scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint) objects. What I've tried so far is the following

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, LinearConstraint

bounds = Bounds(lb=[-0.01] * 200, ub=[0.01] * 200)  # constraint #4
lc = LinearConstraint([[1] * 200], [0.1], [1.1])  # constraint #3
res = minimize(
    fun=diff,
    method='trust-constr',
    x0=w,  # my flattened vector containing w1 first 100 elements, and w2 in last 100 elements
    bounds=bounds,
    constraints=(lc)
)
```

My logic for the `bounds` variable is from constrain #4, and for the `lc` variable comes from constrain #3. However I know I've coded this wrong because because the lower and upper bounds are of length 200 which seems to indicate they are applied to both `w1` and `w2` whereas I only wan't to apply the constrains to `w2` (I get an error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (200,) (100,)` if I try to change the length of the array in `Bounds` from 200 to 100).

The shapes and argument types for `LinearConstraint` are especially confusing to me, but I did try to follow the [scipy example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/optimize.html#defining-linear-constraints).

This current implementation never seems to finish, it just hangs forever.

How do I properly implement `bounds` and `LinearConstraint` so that it satisfies my constraints list above, if that is even possible?

Comment: Side note: can't you pass w1 in the args argument of minimize, so that you don't include it in the fitting procedure (i.e., that it's outside the bounds and constraints)? Or create a closure, so that w1 is fixed in the function to be fitted. I'm not saying this will give you a correct fit, but I'd think it may make things a bit easier.

Comment: That seems to work for part of my issue! Thanks. Now I need to know how to code up the constraints. I'm wondering if #3 or #4 are non-linear...

Comment: Constraint #3 is non-linear, since you are using `abs`.

Comment: Thats what I thought... thanks!

Comment: I have a solution considering a linear constraint and I can post it, but it does not fix constraint #3 (it uses the linear version you implemented).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can easily be formulated as a linear optimization problem (LP). You only need to reformulate all absolute values of the optimization variables.

Changing the notation slightly (x is now the optimization variable w2 and w is just your given vector w1), your problem reads as

```
min |w_1 - x_1| + .... + |w_N - x_N|

s.t. lb <= |x1| + ... + |xN| <= ub         (3)
                       |x_i| <= 0.01 - eps (4) (models the strict inequality)
```

where eps is just a sufficiently small number in order to model the strict inequality.

Let's consider the constraint (3). Here, we add additional positive variables z and define z_i = |x_i|. Then, we replace all absolute values |x_i| by z_i and impose the constraints -x_i <= z_i <= x_i which model the relationship z_i = |x_i|. Similarly, you can proceed with the objective and the constraint (4). The latter is by the way trivial and equivalent to -(0.01 - eps) <= x_i <= 0.01 - eps.

In the end, your optimization problem should read (assuming that all your w_i are positive):

```
min u1 + .... + uN

s.t.      lb <= z1 + ... + zN <= ub
          -x <=      z        <= x
 -0.01 + eps <=      x        <= 0.01 - eps
    -(w-x)   <=      u        <= w - x
          0  <= z
          0  <= u
```

with 3*N optimization variables x1, ..., xN, u1, ..., uN, z1, ..., zN. It isn't hard to write these constraints as an matrix-vector product A_ineq * x <= b_ineq. Then, you can solve it by [`scipy.optimize.linprog`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, linprog

n = 100
w = np.abs(np.random.randn(n))
eps = 1e-10
lb = 0.1
ub = 1.1

# linear constraints: A_ub * (x, z, u)^T <= b_ub
A_ineq = np.block([
    [np.zeros(n), np.ones(n), np.zeros(n)],
    [np.zeros(n), -np.ones(n), np.zeros(n)],
    [-np.eye(n),  np.eye(n), np.zeros((n, n))],
    [-np.eye(n), -np.eye(n), np.zeros((n, n))],
    [ np.eye(n), np.zeros((n, n)), -np.eye(n)],
    [ np.eye(n), np.zeros((n, n)),  np.eye(n)],
])

b_ineq = np.hstack((ub, -lb, np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n), w, w))

# bounds: lower <= (x, z, u)^T <= upper 
lower = np.hstack(((-0.01 + eps) * np.ones(n), np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n)))
upper = np.hstack((( 0.01 - eps) * np.ones(n), np.inf*np.ones(n), np.inf*np.ones(n)))
bounds = [(l, u) for (l, u) in zip(lower, upper)]

# objective: c^T * (x, z, u)
c = np.hstack((np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n), np.ones(n)))

# solve the problem
res = linprog(c, A_ub=A_ineq, b_ub=b_ineq, method="highs")

# your solution
x = res.x[:n]
print(res.message)
print(x)
```

Some notes in arbitrary order:

- It's highly recommended to solve linear optimization problems with `linprog` instead of `minimize`. The former provides an interface to HiGHS, a high-performance LP solver [HiGHs](https://highs.dev/) that outperforms all algorithms under the hood of `minimize`. However, it's also worth mentioning that `minimize` is meant to be used for nonlinear optimization problems.
- In case your values w are not all positive, we need to change the formulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and perhaps should, for clarity), use the `args` argument in `minimize`, and provide the fixed vector as an extra argument to your function.

If you set up your equation as follows:

```
def diff(w2, w1):
    return np.sum(np.absolute(w1 - w2))
```

and your constraints with

```
bounds = Bounds(lb=[-0.01] * 100, ub=[0.01] * 100)  # constraint #4
lc = LinearConstraint([[1] * 100], [0.1], [1.1])  # constraint #3
```

and then do

```
res = minimize(
    fun=diff,
    method='trust-constr',
    x0=w1,
    args=(w2,),
    bounds=bounds,
    constraints=[lc]
)
```

Then:

```
print(res.success, res.status, res.nit, np.abs(res.x).sum(), all(np.abs(res.x) < 0.01))
```

yields (for me at least)

```
(True, 1, 17, 0.9841520351691752, True)
```

which seems to be what you want.

Note that my test inputs are:

```
w1 = (np.arange(100) - 50) / 1000
w2 = np.ones(100, dtype=float)
```

which may or may not be favourable to the fitting procedure.

Comment: The problem of OP is that constraint 3 is not linear, so the definition of `lc` does not reflect the problem.

Comment: True; hurray for absolute values(!) I'll leave this here anyway, as an extended note perhaps.